# React Removing an item from a to do list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

i'm creating a simple react to do list, I'm currently working on a delete button, I have created an array then passed this array into a prop, I then need to splice that item from the prop array when the user clicks the delete button. I was able to store the array number but I cant seem to update the array after its deleted.

CLASS CALL:

```
 <TodoList items={this.state.items} deleteItems={this.deleteItem}/>
```

SUB-CLASS CODE:

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>  
        { this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
          <div className={"col-12"} key={item.id}>
            <div className={"card text-white"}>
              <div className={item.priority}>
                <div className={"col-12 card-body"}>
                  <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                  <p>{item.text}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => { this.removeItem(item, i)}} key={i} className={"col-12 btn btn-primary bg-red"}>Delete</button> 
                </div>         
              <div/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>

    );

  }
  removeItem(e, i) {
    this.props.items.splice(i, '');
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

I have been looking at different stack questions but none of the solutions seem to apply to this, thanks for any constructive feedback :)

Comment: You might want to read about immutability. It's a good starting point. :-)

Comment: Ill give it a read, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Props are supposed to be immutable, you shouldn't modify them and expect your component to re-render. You didn't explain where the array comes from but you should call a prop function so that whatever manages that prop can delete the item e.g. `props.removeItem(someuniqueId/someIndex)`. Also you shouldn't use splice with nothing else as it doesn't create a new reference, using `filter` would be preferable. Starting with local state would be easier.

Comment: I believe <TodoList /> should have its own state

Comment: You have to define the remove item in parent component and call the function using props.

Answer (score 5):

I believe `<TodoList />` component should have its own state. However, if you can't do so, there's 2 solutions to this problem:

- Keep `<ToDoList />` component's state and props in sync (In case the parent component modifies the state passed down as items). Then modify the `<TodoList />` 's state.
- Declare a method that removes the item inside the parent component which has the 
  state, and pass it down as props (**Recommended**)

Example code:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = {   
    items: [1, 2, 3]
  }

  removeItem = index => () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.filter((_, i) => i !== index) //Filter the items
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <TodoList items={this.state.items} deleteItems={this.removeItem} />
    );
  }
}
```

**Important:** Always use pure functions to modify the state. Do not use `.splice()` or `.push()` (If you haven't cloned the state yet). It's always safer to use `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.concat()`, etc.